# Fields such that there is a single surface into which every curve embeds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For which fields $k$ does there exist a proper morphism $S\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:k$ of relative dimension $\leq 2$ such that for every geometrically connected smooth proper $C \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:k$ of relative dimension $1$ there exists a $k$-closed immersion $C\rightarrow S$?

Complex numbers are not such a field (in fact, a stronger result [holds](https://mathoverflow.net/a/221969/140765)), some "massaging" might extend this to all subfields of $\mathbb{C}$. No idea what is going on in $\mathrm{char}\:p$.

Comment: The proof you linked to works for all uncountable algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$. I think you need a new idea to extend it to say, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}.$ For (uncountable algebraically closed) fields of characteristic $p$, this seems closely related to asking if $M_g$ is unirational for large $g$, and to my knowledge this is still open (see the final remarks in https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04404).

Comment: Is it known whether such fields exist at all?

Comment: @AviSteiner not known to me, that's for sure