# A proper analytic surface into which every smooth proper analytic curve embeds

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

Let $k$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Does there exist a proper $k$-analytic surface such that there is a closed immersion into it from any connected smooth proper $k$-analytic curve? The definitions are as stated in [this](http://www.math.huji.ac.il/~temkin/papers/Introduction_to_Berkovich_Spaces.pdf) file.

[A similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/221957/140765) in the Archimedean setting has been asked on MO.